# how to split a matrix by given criteria

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a matrix

```
j=randn(3,17)
M=[1;10;6]
```

I want to split the `j` matrix by its first row and the consecutive 10 rows, and then the rest 6. As a result, I want to have three different matrices.

Assume I don't see the size of `M`, nor its content. In that sense, how can I automate splitting the `j` matrix according to the unknown size and content of `M`? I would like to avoid using nested `for` loops.

Comment: Your question implies that `M` has exactly 17 rows-. Why do you say "Assume I don't see the size of `M`"?

Comment: @Luis Mendo - I took it as `M could be of any size and value` given that the sum of `M` is equal to the size of `J`. Not sure it is the right view though!

Comment: @macduf Oh, that makes sense! I read too fast

Comment: @macduf ; yes the sum of content of M is equal to size the so called j matrix.

Comment: @macduf my goal is to split the matrix according to repetitive rows. So far, the solutions I have seen are driving me to use cell arrays, that is what I want to avoid. In that sense, is there anyway to use double arrays.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to use `mat2cell` for splitting a matrix.

In your case,

```
J = randn(3,17)
M = [1;10;6]
C = mat2cell(J, size(J,1), M)
```

where `C{1}` to `C{3}` are your matrices.

By the way it's not a good practice to call a matrix `j` as it is already defined by matlab.

Comment: is there any other way by not engaging in cells. Because, cells force me to use for loops to access elements of them